# how to remove everything after a particular string from an array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have an array of strings from which I want to remove anything after `with` in the statement.
For example, let's take a string

```
var str = ['hey what is with you guys',
'you mean with out', 
'hello no with is you']
```

the new str2 should return

```
['hey what is', 
'you mean' ,
'hello no'
]
```

I have written the following code but it is not giving the desirable output.
My code:

```
function newArray(str){
    for (var i = 0; i <= (str.length - 1); i++){
        var k = str[i].toString()
        j = k.split('with')
        var arr2 = []
        var newArr = arr2.concat(j[0])
        console.log(newArr)
        
    }
    return newArr
}


var str = ['hey what is with you guys',
'you mean with out', 
'hello no with is you']

newArray(str)
```

the output is

```
[ 'hey what is ' ]
[ 'you mean ' ]
[ 'hello no ' ]
```

However, I want my output

```
['hey what is', 
'you mean' ,
'hello no'
]
```

Comment: You seem to not only want to remove everything after "with", but also the word "with", and any whitespace before it. Your described "the output is" are the `console.log` in your loop, one after another, not actually a continuous array. You can try `.map(s => s.match(/^(.*?)(\s*with|$)/)[1])`. Your attempt could be made to work, by removing `var arr2 = []`, changing the following line to `newArr = newArr.concat(j[0].trimEnd());`, and putting `var newArr = [];` before the loop.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes, it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Small addendum: The fix above still has one small issue. It would trim whitespace at the end, even if there was no "with" in the string. E.g. the input `['nothing to find here but spaces      ']` would return `['nothing to find here but spaces']`. You'd have to check, whether `split` actually splits, to also cover that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason to split the strings into arrays and then join them back into strings; you could manage everything using methods of the String object:

#### "modern" ES6+ solution

```js
function newStrings(arr, str) {
  return arr.map(string => {
    const index = string.indexOf(str);
    return index > 0 ? string.substr(0, index).trim() : string;
  })
}

//test
const original = [
  'hey what is with you guys',
  'you mean with out',
  'hello no with is you'
];

const modified = newStrings(original, 'with')

console.log('original:', original);
console.log('modified', modified);
```

#### "classic" solution

```js
function newStrings(arr, str) {
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var myString = arr[i];
    var index = myString.indexOf(str);
    var outStr = index > 0 ? myString.substr(0, index).trim() : myString;
    output.push(outStr);
  }

  return output
}

//test
var original = [
  'hey what is with you guys',
  'you mean with out',
  'hello no with is you'
];

var modified = newStrings(original, 'with')

console.log('original:', original);
console.log('modified', modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution proposal, using ES6 Features such as [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const str = [
  'hey what is with you guys',
  'you mean with out',
  'hello no with is you',
];

function removeWith(arr) {
  // Creates an array from an input array
  return arr.map((line) => {
    // For each line, split the string with the word "with"
    // I use a Regex with the `insensitive` flag to make it case insensitive.
    // So it works with "with" and "With" and "wiTH" ...
    return line.split(/with/i)[0];
    // [0] will return the first part of the string, even if nothing was split.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and it worked.

```js
var str = ['hey what is with you guys',
'you mean with out', 
'hello no with is you']
let arr2 = []
function newArray(str){
  for (var i = 0; i <= (str.length - 1); i++){
      var k = str[i].toString()
      let j = k.split('with')
      arr2.push(j[0])  
  }
  return arr2;
}

let ans = newArray(str);
console.log(ans)
```